# How to send and execute current line of code in gedit to terminal using external tools?

Tags: terminal, text-editor, gedit

I just switched from Mac to Ubuntu. I am writing R scripts using Gedit. When I was using R in Mac, I was able to send current line of code or a selection of code to terminal. However, I have no idea how to do such a thing now.

Note: I am not a Linux user, so you may have to spell it out for me.

This is what I am looking for . How is this done??

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4jJDkcEs5yw

I am also happy to see how other people achieve this using other text editors

Comment: Copy and paste?  Or do you mean something else?

Answer (score 6):

A good way of doing this is to use external tools in gedit.

Do the following:
gedit -> Edit -> Preferences -> Plugins -> Check External Tools

Then:
gedit -> Tools -> Manage External Tools

Here:
Add a tool by clicking on the '+' button.

Name: Run line
Shortcut Key: Alt+L (or whatever you are comfortable with)
Save: Nothing
Input: Current Line
Output: Display in bottom pane

Put this code in the **Edit** section:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import sys
import commands

line = sys.stdin.read()
print commands.getoutput(line)
```

Name: Run select
Shortcut Key: Alt+B (or whatever you are comfortable with)
Save: Nothing
Input: Current selection
Output: Display in bottom pane

Put this code in the **Edit** section:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import sys
import commands

line = sys.stdin.read().replace("\r","")
print commands.getoutput(line)
```

Comment: I'm using the second snippet, in an attempt to run the whole document. I of course set my input to `Current selection(default to document)`. This error is produced `sh: 1: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")`

Comment: Sometimes copy-pasting directly from browser causes weird character mapping issues. Check that the quotes are correctly copied to gedit.

Comment: I've run into this before. Not this time though. Typed it in myself.

Comment: Hmm, it's possible that the selection that you are trying to execute itself has some issues. Try selecting some simple commands to ensure that's not the case.

Comment: Eureka! `True == True` produces `Running tool: run  source` nl `sh: 1: True: not found` nl `Done.` It looks telling, though I don't know what it means.

Comment: O.O looks like `True==True` produces `Running tool: run source` nl nl nl `Done.`. So I tried `print(True==True)` and it produced the same error from my top most comment, so then I tried `print True==True` and it produced the weirdest error of all: `Running tool: run source` nl `sh: 2: Syntax error: ";" unexpected` nl `Done.`

Comment: I figured it out. If you're curios here's the link http://askubuntu.com/questions/768558/is-it-possible-to-send-selected-codewhole-documents-to-the-gedit-terminal-for

Comment: in python3 commands module has been depreciated. some alternative for the run line code:
`#!/usr/bin/env python3`  
`import sys`  
`import subprocess`  
`line = sys.stdin.read()`  
`print(subprocess.getoutput(line))`